# To call a Javascript function when browser tab closed and not when refreshed/reloaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a django project and the following function is my Javascript code. What I intend to do is, before the browser tab is closed I want to clear some database entries in the backend. The following code serves the purpose if before I close the tab I do not refresh the browser tab. But if I do refresh the browser tab before I close it, this function gets called and my database entries are cleaned cause of which nothing is displayed on my web page anymore.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
    var ip="{{ip}}";
    clearDB(ip);
    return null;
}
        
function clearDB(ip)
{
    $.ajax({
            url: '/clearDatabase/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'ip':ip},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                            
            },
            error: function (){
            
            }
                        
        }); 
}
```

How can I call this function only when the tab is closed and not when the page is refreshed/reloaded?

Comment: short answer - you can't distinguish between the two

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you

Comment: Please don't take that as a definitive answer ... my comment is based on several same, or very similar, questions (and the answers given there) being asked on SO in the last 2 days or so

Comment: Sure... Still waiting if if there is a work around

Comment: why would you store something you will need to erase later ? maybe could you store data on the user's session storage ?